# Class objects into many variables

Tags: python, class, oop

I am not sure if my title is right but, nevertheless,

say I have a class like this

```
>>> class Example(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.foo = " Hello world "
...     def bye(self):
...             print(" Bye ")
... 
>>> ex = Example()
>>> ex1 = Example()
>>> ex2 = Example()
>>> ex.bye()
 Bye 
>>> print(ex1.foo)
 Hello world 
>>>
```

And I want `Example()` to be given to many other variables, 20-30-40, doesn't matter, is there a way of doing that instead of manually? By manually I mean like in the example:

```
>>> ex = Example()
>>> ex1 = Example()
>>> ex2 = Example()
```

Comment: I would go with the answer provided, but another option would be to use `exec`. As in `for x in range(10): exec("ex{} = Example()".format(x))`. This will create a bunch of them named `ex0...ex9`. This is somewhat messy. It's always best to put things in containers.

Comment: @Abdou After carefully reading your comment I realized that is what I actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when you want to create a bunch of related somethings, it would be vastly more convenient to put them in a list or other container, rather than individual variables.  You can loop over the container to do something to all the items, whereas you'd have to duplicate code to do something with multiple individual variables.  Try this (read about 'list comprehensions' if you don't understand how the first line works):

```
exes = [Example() for n in range(30)]
exes[11].bye()
for ex in exes:
    print(ex.foo)
```

Comment: Works amazing !